# May the top margin text be shorter than the title text?

Tags: section-titles

Some times the  text in the top margin matching a section, or subsection, title, is too long. Is there a way to use *There is a long and winding road* as subsection title, and *the long an winding road* as top margin text?

Comment: That's the purpose of the optional argument of the sectioning commands: `\section[The long and winding road]{There is a long and winding road that leads to your door}`

Comment: Many thanks! :)

Comment: @Mane32 Incidentally, what is the name of the text in the top margin?

Comment: "running head" normally (or page header)